# Remove left space in toolbar android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I had add some view inside Toolbar but there is showing some left padding which I want to remove.

[image]
I want to remove those 'Remove this space section.

Here is my xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.swornimlab.swornimlab.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            >
            <include
                layout="@layout/layout_inside_toolbar" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

View which I want to add inside toolbar:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:text="Hello, Asmin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="Welcome Home"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_vc"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: R u need Hamburger button

Answer (score 10):

Just add these two lines in your Toolbar in XML

```js
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` from layout.

And add `app:contentInsetStart` and `app:contentInsetEnd` to the **Toolbar** :

For e.g.

```
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

So your code looks like this :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
            
                        <include
                            layout="@layout/layout_inside_toolbar" />
            
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

> layout_inside_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        
        <TextView
            android:text="Hello, Asmin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="Welcome Home"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_vc"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: also remove android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: I think it's because of navigation menu icon

Comment: for your answer! i was looking for this solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

This seems to be issue.

Also on another note, i would suggest you to use percentRelativelayout for your layout distribution. Using weight with your linear layout is very expensive

Comment: I changed to Relative layout but didn't work. I think it's because of navigation icon